# Big white circle on scanned negative

Tags: film, scanning, ilford

I just developed a roll of film and I'm noticing big white circles. They seem to appear in different places, from one picture to another. All I can think of is wrong temperature of development (21C instead of 24), or residuals in the development.

The lens I'm using is brand new and I kept the film in the fridge until the day before using it.

What could it be? The film is Ilford HP5 Plus.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are they on the negative itself (look at the actual negative)?  If so, they're probably water drops.  You need to use a wetting agent (e.g. Kodak Photo-Flo) to avoid water marks.

If they're not on the negative itself, it's some sort of scanning artifact.  Try scanning again.

Comment: oh.. I just realized I did not remove the water before drying the negative... that might explain it

Comment: If you use Photo Flo, you won't need to remove the water, or at least, can be a lot less thorough about the task.  The wetting agent will prevent the water from leaving spots.